# How to validate emails in PHP using filter_var() function.

Tags: php

i have this line for validation email and non empty email field:

```
if ( filter_var($tmpEmail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)  == TRUE) || (!empty($email)) {
...
}
```

but i see this error :

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '||' (T_BOOLEAN_OR) in
```

how to fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [**`filter_var()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) function from the PHP manual, which can manipulate/validate strings orders.

```
$email = 'foo@foo.com'; 
if ((filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) == TRUE) || !empty($email)) {
   // your email is correct. 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your parentheses are mismatched. Try:

```
if ( filter_var($tmpEmail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) || !empty($email)) {
```

Answer (score 2):

The `)` after `TRUE` ends the `if` statement, remove that and the `(` before `!empty`.